# How to solve Logarithm in case of addition with same bases

Tags: logarithms

How to solve $\log (15+9)=24$
and how to get an Exponential value of 24 with base 10 if
$\log 2$ value is given,
$\log 3$ value is given,
and $\log 5$ is given?
and suppose if I start with 
$\log (5×3+3^2)=24$
$\log(5)+\log(3)+2\log3=24$
then how to solve further?​
Is this correct?
$\log(5×3+3^2)=\log 5+\log 3+2\log3$????

Comment: $\log(5×3+3^2)=\log 5+\log 3+2\log 3$ is NOT correct. It holds for products: $\log(a*b)=\log(a)+\log(b)$, but not for sums inside the logarithm. You could write $\log(5×3+3^2)= \log(3)+\log(5+3)$.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of $\log_{10}{24}$ by just knowing the valus of $\log_{10}(2)$ and $\log_{10}(3)$ you have to write $24$ as a product $24=2^3\cdot3$ now you can use what I wrote in the comments what holds for products inside the logarithm $$\log_{10}(24)=\log_{10}(2^3\cdot3)=\log_{10}(2^3)+\log_{10}(3)=3\cdot\log_{10}(2)+\log_{10}(3).$$ Thus knowing the value of $\log_{10}(5)$ is not relevant at this time, which can be seen by all numbers $2,3,5$ are prime and $5$ is not a primefactor of $24$.

Since I'm not sure if this was exactly your question maybe this helps you to solve your problem: for every base $b$ of the logarithm holds
$$\log_b(24)=\frac{\log_{10}(24)}{\log_{10}(b)}.$$ So if your first question was to solve $$\log_b(24)=24$$ for $b$ you have to calculate
$$\log_{10}(b)=\frac{\log_{10}(24)}{24}$$ as above and then taking its exponetial with respect to $10$ to get the value of $b$.

Comment: I mean to ask that if i approach through log(5×3+3^2)=24. So further how to expand ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. First of all to which base do you mean your logarithm? What do you mean by 'approach'? Please try to ask clear questions and don't forget to write down always every information, otherwise I can't help you. The only possibility to give "solve $\log(24)=24$" a meaning is, that you forgot to write the base and this is what might be looking for.

Comment: If nothing is given Then it was common sense to assume base 10 and secondly It cannot be base e as i would have written Ln instead.  And Question is log 24 to base 10 can be approached by log (5×3+3^2)? if  yes then how to solve further or expand the Above expression if in the question value of log 3 log 5 log 2 is given (BASE 10 10 10 )

Comment: I still don't get it. Do you want to approximate $24$ or $\log_{10}(24)$, by using the values of $\log 2,\ \log 3\ \log5$ ? If the answerer is $\log_{10}(24)$, then the solution is given in answer above. If the answer is $24$, then use the prime factorization $24=\log_{10}(10^{24})=\log_{10}(2^{24}5^{24})=24\log_{10}(2)+24\log_{10}(5)$.

Comment: Ok just say how to solve Log (15+9) using Log 2 value ,log 3 value and log 5 value .(Take base 10)

Comment: As I already wrote above: $\log (15+9)=\log 24 =3\log 2+\log 3$. Yout don't need the value of $\log5$.